# How to notify my WPF application that my SQL query skipped duplicate rows when inserting to database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, duplicates, where-clause

I am using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` SQL statement to filter away duplicates when doing an `INSERT`.

How can I notify my WPF-application user that a duplicate has been skipped?

Comment: Well, your WPF app knows how many items of data you've sent to be stored - so you could check how many have *actually* been saved, and if there's a difference there, some (or all) have been skipped ... I bet just about any RDBMS using SQL can somehow return the number of actual rows inserted ....

Comment: By selecting/counting the number of duplicates using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the SQL variable `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Added it to my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_procedure_name]
    @rowCount int output
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (/* column list */)
        SELECT /* columns */
        FROM [dbo].[another_table_name]
    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    RETURN
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And then, in my C# code:

```
SqlParameter param = new();
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Close();
int rows = cmd.Parameters["@rowCount"].Value.ToString();
```